# Screen Sleeps During Video Playback

Tags: video, screen, sleep, playback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop the screensaver from turning on when I watching online videos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144621/how-do-i-stop-the-screensaver-from-turning-on-when-i-watching-online-videos)

On Ubuntu Natty,

My screen goes to sleep during video playback, I tried googling for a solution, but none of it worked.